# how do append html returned from web service

Tags: jquery

This is my webservice code and I'm returning my user control in html format, how do I read that html and append that to my form tag in the main page:

```
System.Web.UI.Page page = new System.Web.UI.Page();
TestControl myCOntrol = (TestControl)page.LoadControl("TestControl.ascx");
myCOntrol.FillTable(name, email, dob, country, gender, meal);
StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter myStringWriter = new StringWriter(myStringBuilder);
HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myStringWriter);

myCOntrol.RenderControl(myWriter);
string html = myStringWriter.ToString();
return html;
```

How do I append this to my form tag?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService1.asmx/UserInfo",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ name: name , email : email, dob:dob, country:country, gender:gender, meal:meal }),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (html) {
        jQuery("#form1").append(html);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

The above code is my jQuery code.

Comment: Did you get proper string with html in your success function ?

Comment: Are you getting value on `html`

Comment: yes i'm getting..

Comment: @ChandrashekharM is this html? and any error on console?

Comment: when i go web service i'm getting the proper html,, i can see that by copy pasting the obtained html code,, but i'm not getting exact data when  i append that using jquery. @ kiran shahi @Mirko Acimovic

Comment: try to see what you are getting as a response, you can console log it or use debugger. If the proper html string is leaving service call then the object you are receiving as a response is not plain JSON format but maybe nested inside response object. You can always use JSON serializer on server side to send proper object format to frontend.

Comment: @ Mirko Acimovic -- okay i'll try

Comment: @ChandrashekharM - if you can copy and paste your html variable here

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by replacing .append with .html function

```
jQuery("#form1").append(html);
```